# Can't use MediaQuery with the builder parameter of MaterialApp in flutter's new versions

Tags: flutter, dart

I was able to use this code in previous versions of Flutter:

```
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: data.copyWith(
          textScaleFactor: data.textScaleFactor * _settings.appFontSizeFactor),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

**But, with new versions of Flutter, if I use it like above, I get this error:**
*The argument type 'MediaQuery Function(BuildContext, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable*

This only happens with new versions of Flutter. My other apps written in previous Flutter versions can still use like above. I can't find the new way of using MediaQuery in the builder parameter of MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you don't mean "new versions of Flutter", you mean "null-safe versions of dart acting in modern mode, not legacy mode".  Please don't blame a flutter upgrade for this problem.  Blame yourself for trying to shortcut past the steps listed at https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.  I'm betting you edited your pubspec.yaml minimumsdk directly.  Don't do that.

Comment: I already know about that. Please read the question carefully. I don't question about the new versions, I want to know that how do people now use this MediaQuery to change MaterialApp's textScaleFactor. In older versions we were able to use it like above. That's all. I understand what that error means. This is from completely new project. Maybe you can show the "modern way" if you really know.

Comment: Have you tried running `dart migrate` on an older version of the code to see what the changes would be?

Comment: I fixed it and added my answer. If you edit your answer* and add the exact solution I posted, I can choose your answer over mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) { // updated line
    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: data.copyWith(
          textScaleFactor: data.textScaleFactor * _settings.appFontSizeFactor),
      child: child!,  // updated line
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

That's all. This is about the null safety.

Comment: You've traded compile time safety for runtime exceptions.  If it really should abort your program, good job.  However, you'll probably want to ensure upstream that a Widget gets passed, not a "Widget?".

Comment: This is what the 'dart migrate' command you suggested does.  :)